# Bash completion overwrites current word

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I am trying to create a bash completion script for my command. `ls` has the behaviour that I want. I need to get this same behaviour form my command.

This is what I get for `ls`

```
$ ls /home/tux/<Tab><Tab>
Downloads  Documents  Pictures
$ ls /home/tux/Do<Tab><Tab>
Downloads  Documents
```

I.e. bash only shows the next paths relatively, not absolutely (i.e. it does add `Downloads` to the completion list, but not `/home/tux/Downloads`)

I wanted to write a completion script that works the same way. This is what I have tried.

```
_testcommand ()
{
    local IFS=$'\n'
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -o bashdefault -d -- "$cur") )
    if [ "${#COMPREPLY[@]}" -ne 1 ]
    then
        # remove prefix "$cur", so the preview of paths gets shorter
        local cur_len=$(echo $cur | sed 's|/[^/]*$||' | wc -c)
        for i in ${!COMPREPLY[@]}
        do
            COMPREPLY[$i]="${COMPREPLY[i]:$cur_len}"
        done
    fi
    return 0
}

complete -o nospace -F _testcommand testcommand
```

However the result is like this:

```
$ testcommand /home/tux/<Tab><Tab>
Downloads  Documents  Pictures
$ testcommand /home/tux/Do<Tab>
Downloads  Documents
$ testcommand Do
```

How can I make my completion *not* remove `/home/tux/` from the command line?

Note: I think I can not add '-f' or '-d' etc. to the `complete` call on the bottom. In reality, the completion must, in some cases, also complete words instead of paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most programs in the bash completion dir (`pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion`) use the `_filedir` function provided by bash-completion itself. It seems legitimate to reuse `_filedir` - No need to worry about your own implementation!

**MWE:**

```
_testcommand()
{
    # init bash-completion's stuff
    _init_completion || return

    # fill COMPREPLY using bash-completion's routine
    # in this case, accept only MarkDown and C files
    _filedir '@(md|c)'
}
complete -F _testcommand testcommand
```

Of course, you can still use this while completing non-files:

```
if ...
then
    # any custom extensions, e.g. words, numbers etc
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen ...) )
else
    # fill COMPREPLY using bash-completion's routine
    _filedir '@(md|c)'
fi
```

**How did I find it?**

Thanks to **@csm**: Using their answer, check `type _longopt`, which calls `_filedir`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check which completion function is used by "ls": `complete -p | grep ls`.
And you can check the function with: `type _longopt` (the previous command's result). In the `_longopt` function you can find the `_filedir` function.

And finally an interesting article about completion: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/14/bash-programmable-completion/

Comment: Thanks, the `complete -p` was helpful to find a solution. As this is just a hint to how to get the solution, I've added a full example of how to do it. Adding "$1" does not really help, it only adds "testcommand" to the completion - have you tried it? If you fix/remove/explain this, I'll reward you with the bounty.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, my first solution didn't work. I tried it and it worked for me, but maybe I forgot to source the last version. (Now it works as you explained). I found the _filedir function but I supposed you wanted to write a custom function